# ElasticSearch Python client how to define number of shards when creating index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I only need to have 1 shard for my index, but having a glance on the [documentation](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html) and google search doesn't give any clue on how to do it via the python client without using raw json format.

I would expect something like:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

es.indices.create(index='test-index', shards=1)
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but try to specify settings in the body:

```
es.indices.create(index='test-index', body={
   'settings' : {
         'index' : {
              'number_of_shards':1 
         }
   }
})
```

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/32239539f9c1f502c1506977f7a19d6bef4ccbfd/elasticsearch/client/indices.py#L74

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html